# Android UDP Socket IOException: sendto failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I wrote an application in Android that communicates with a UDP socket periodically.
I create a datagramSocket and I periodically send and receive a packet from the server every 5 seconds, this is a part of the code:

```
Thread commTh = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket();
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            ds.connect(serverAddr, port);

            while(exitThread) {

                ....

                DatagramPacket dp;
                dp = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(),
                        data.length(), serverAddr, port);

                ds.setSoTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

                ds.send(dp);

                byte[] lMsg = new byte[SOCKET_BYTE];
                dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
                ds.receive(dp);

                ....

                Thread.sleep(5000);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
});
```

Randomly after a few tens of minutes I get this exception:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: sendto failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
W/System.err:     at         libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:576)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:544)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:125)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:721)
```

why I get an operation not permitted? I have internet permissions in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: can you show the code in question?

Comment: perhaps it happens during network transitions, wifi drops, etc? I think some OSes block networking with EPERM either when the interface is down and/or during dhcp, etc, but I don't know anything about Android specifically.

Comment: Same is happening with me, I am also using 5 sec delay. Did you found any fix for this? @Daniele

Comment: _Possibly_ related: [How to fix `EPERM` error when trying to use `sendto()` with Ethernet `socket(AF_INET, ..., ...)` (IP output packets) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74522605/4561887)